# Angular 2 - How to bind a result of an eventEmitter to a property

Tags: angular

How can i bind a template property to  the result of an eventEmitter:

something like that in a ngFor:

```
<ion-img [src]="item.imageFound" class="listImg" ></ion-img>
```

item.imageFound is declared as follow:

```
@Output() imageFound = new EventEmitter();
```

And emited:

```
this.imageFound.emit(value: 'http:\\....');
```

Comment: Where is that event emitter coming from?
A separate component or a service?

Comment: A service (component==>service=>service)

Comment: So, what is the flow? Is item an element in a larger array or is it just returning the observable for just one image in the item?

Comment: A begining, i was using 'code'<ion-img [src]="item.getImg()"'code'. but i was loosing context, and get error 'code'TypeError: self.context.$implicit.getImg is not a function'code'

Comment: it s an element in a larger array

Comment: so each item has an image?

Comment: yes (yeah, i must to care of perf)

Comment: why are you waiting for an image found?

Comment: there is a process to identify the image to download

Comment: `EventEmitter` is not supposed to be used in a service - only for `@Output()` in a component or directive. Use a `Subject` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `EventEmitter` is extending `Observable` but the Angular team mentioned that that is likely to change. `EventEmitter` should not be used this way.

Your question doesn't provide enough information to know how your components are related but it could look like:

```
<item (imageFound)="img.setAttribute('src', $event)"></item>
<!-- or just -->
<item (imageFound)="img.src=$event"></item>

<ion-img #img class="listImg" ></ion-img>
```

I assumed that the component containing the `imageFount` `EventEmitter` is a sibling of the `<ion-img>` component.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if I got the point but it may be the answer to your question.

To use observable values in template there is an `async` pipe:

```
<ion-img [src]="item.imageFound | async" class="listImg" ></ion-img>
```

It will put the latest value of a stream to `[src]`

Comment: thanks, i didn't know that eventEmitter is observable! i Can't upvote, lack of reputation

Comment: @JeromeXoo now you can :) and this also helped me